How to display a (Login) dialog before MainWindow in Avalonia?
I want my program first opens a LoginWindow (as a dialog) for login.After successful login, open the MainWindow, which displays different menus based on the login account permissions.
Simply creating the settings dialog from the App.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted method and displaying it with MyLoginWindow.ShowDialog. This fails because ShowDialog requires a parent window.
var window = new MyLoginWindow();
window.ShowDialog(ownerWindow);


I am currently using this method. How to create Splash Screen | AvaloniaUI Cross Platform #1
Show login window: desktop.MainWindow = loginWindow; .
After user logged in: desktop.MainWindow = mainWindow;.
if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            var mvm = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();
            var lvm = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<LoginPageViewModel>();
            
            var loginWindow = new LoginWindow()
            {
                DataContext = lvm
            };
            lvm.LoginSuccess += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var mainWindow = new MainWindow()
                {
                    DataContext=mvm
                };
                mainWindow.Show();
                loginWindow.Close();
                desktop.MainWindow = mainWindow;
            };
            desktop.MainWindow = loginWindow;
            loginWindow.Show();
        }


A dialog requires a parent window in Avalonia UI because it is cross platform and mobile platforms (iOS and Android) do not support the concepts of a Window or a Dialog. It's done this way to maintain universal compatibility.
There are ways to work around this, however.  You could present your Dialog as the main window, and then have that load the content window after login.
Your best option, however, is to simply rebuff the dated concept of a modal dialog and make a view that presents itself before the content view while working in the same window and even in the same MainView.  With this method your MainView would host a ContentPresenter and the Content property on that would be swapped out after a successful login.  The MainWindow should have no application code (mostly unmodified from the default template) as it will only serve as a host on desktop environments for the MainView (mobile apps use the MainView directly).  I strongly recommend this approach because it is compatible with mobile platforms and even if you aren't planning on mobile now, you might change your mind later. You can even use an TransitioningContentControl to add a little animation.
